# CollectionView Auto Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So I have some code that I am using to auto scroll a collectionView and it is giving me lots of problems. It works based off of a timer that calls a certain function every 3.5 seconds to scroll to a certain item in the collectionView. The code is included belwo

```
import UIKit

class HomeFeedCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var homeFeedController: HomeFeedController?
    let emptyView = UIView()
    //Timer user for call autoscroller of top collection view
    private var timer:Timer?
    var scrollTimer = Timer()
    private let cellId = "cellId"
    var featuredEvents: [Event]?{
        didSet {
            homeFeedCollectionView.reloadData()

        }
    }

    var titles: String? {
        didSet {
            guard let titles = titles else {
            return
            }
//            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titles, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 100)])
            sectionNameLabel.text = titles
//            sectionNameLabel.attributedText = attributedText
        }
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setTimer()
        setupViews()
    }

    func setTimer(){
        //auto scroll method to call every 2.5 seconds interval
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.startTimer(theTimer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let sectionNameLabel : UILabel =  {
        let sectionNameLabel = UILabel()
        sectionNameLabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 36.0)
        return sectionNameLabel
    }()

    lazy var emptyLabel: UILabel = {
        let emptyLabel = UILabel()
        emptyLabel.text = "Sorry We Currently Have No Events, \n In This Category Near You"
        emptyLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 14)
        emptyLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        emptyLabel.textAlignment = .center
        return emptyLabel
    }()

    lazy var iconImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()

    let homeFeedCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .clear
        return cv
    }()

    @objc func setupViews(){
        backgroundColor = .clear
        addSubview(homeFeedCollectionView)
        addSubview(sectionNameLabel)
        sectionNameLabel.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 2, paddingLeft: 4, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        homeFeedCollectionView.anchor(top: sectionNameLabel.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        homeFeedCollectionView.delegate = self
        homeFeedCollectionView.dataSource = self
        homeFeedCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        homeFeedCollectionView.register(HomeFeedEventCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let currentEventCount = featuredEvents?.count else{
            return 0
        }
        if currentEventCount == 0 {
            print("no events")
            setupEmptyDataSet()
        }else{
            emptyView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        return currentEventCount
    }

    @objc func setupEmptyDataSet(){
        self.addSubview(emptyView)
        emptyView.backgroundColor = .clear
        emptyView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(self)
        }
        emptyView.addSubview(iconImageView)
        iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-face-100")
        iconImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.center.equalTo(emptyView)
        }

        emptyView.addSubview(emptyLabel)
        emptyLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.bottom.equalTo(iconImageView.snp.bottom).offset(30)
            make.left.right.equalTo(emptyView)
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 5, bottom: 20, right: 5)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
         return CGSize(width: frame.width - 40, height: frame.height - 40)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let eventDetails = EventDetailViewController()
        eventDetails.currentEvent = featuredEvents?[indexPath.item]
    homeFeedController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(eventDetails, animated: true)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! HomeFeedEventCell
        cell.event = featuredEvents?[indexPath.item]
        var rowIndex = indexPath.row
        let numberOfRecords = (featuredEvents?.count)! - 1
        if rowIndex < numberOfRecords {
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        }else{
            rowIndex = 0
        }

        scrollTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.startTimer(theTimer:)), userInfo: rowIndex, repeats: true)
        return cell
    }

    @objc func startTimer(theTimer: Timer){

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            if let currentIndexPath = self.homeFeedCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.last{

                //Check visible cell is last cell of top collection view then set first index as visible
                if currentIndexPath.item == self.homeFeedCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)-1{
                    let nextIndexPath = NSIndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
                    //top collection view scroller in first item
                    self.homeFeedCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: nextIndexPath as IndexPath, at: .right, animated: false)
                }else{
                    //create next index path from current index path of the top collection view
                    let nextIndexPath = NSIndexPath(item: currentIndexPath.item + 1, section: 0)
                    //top collection view scroller to next item
                    self.homeFeedCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: nextIndexPath as IndexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
                }
            }

        }) { (finished) in
            if finished {
                print("done")
            }
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.homeFeedCollectionView.scrollToNearestVisibleCollectionViewCell()
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        if !decelerate {
            self.homeFeedCollectionView.scrollToNearestVisibleCollectionViewCell()
        }
    }
}
```

Im not really sure what I am doing wrong, to be honest. But my problems with this approach are

1. When you I first enter the collectionView it goes straight to the third item
2. It sometimes scrolls to a certain item may be the first or the third and then it just gets stuck there and stops moving. It tried to move but it just keeps getting stuck.

Comment: why you start timer on `cellForItemAt` ?

Comment: @arash followed the tutorial

Comment: share the link pls

Comment: Try Using this `CollectionView` which pretty much does what you want. It is easy to implement as well: https://github.com/BadhanGanesh/BJAutoScrollingCollectionView

Comment: can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: a screenshot of what?

Answer (score 0):

You have a viewController for the view that shows up what you want and contains collectionView. This class should implement UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate:

```
class viewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
```

in this class you should implement the `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellForItemAt` methods.

and you need another class for cells in the collectionView:

```
class customCell: UICollectionViewCell
```

in this class you could define `IBOutlets` or what ever you want related to each cell ***NOT*** collectionView

and in last you should fire the timer in `viewDidLoad` (or `viewDidAppear`) instead of `cellForItemAt` delegate,
that func calls for each row then you start timers as number of cells that your collectionView has.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    scrollTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.startTimer(theTimer:)), userInfo: rowIndex, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: ummm could you help me with syntax

Comment: its inside a cell

Comment: no inside `viewController` class, it will be good if you add more code

Comment: I think you confused and mixed up the codes, check the edit

Comment: are you there by any chance

Comment: I see your edits but my class is a collectionview with cells that have collectionViews in them

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pod https://cocoapods.org/pods/AutoScrollCollectionView
https://github.com/mohankrishnameruva/AutoScrollCollectionView

Subclass your collection view from **'AutoScrollCollectionView'** in storyboard and 
whenever you want to start scroll call this method 
 on collectionView **startAutoScrolling(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(exactly: 2.0)!)**